# i am getting connection error on prod not localhost

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I am trying to connect to cloud mongo db using mongoose with the connection string

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect(
        "mongodb+srv://<user>:<pass>@<cluster>/<db>?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        }
    ).then(res => {
        console.log("successful" + res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("connection error:", err);
    })

module.exports = mongoose;
```

This works fine on my local machine but when I upload and run it on my production server it doesn't connect.
I have to set it to allow connections from all IPs and I have also add my server IP to it but still it shows me the same error

Comment: The error message would be helpful.

Comment: It could very well be your server has a firewall